# How intercept the "Cancel" and "OK" actions belonging to the native IOS picker component?

Tags: datepicker, codenameone

I have a question about the Picker component in Codename One. How can I intercept the "Cancel" and "OK" actions belonging to the native IOS picker component? In my UI specifications, I need to differentiate this two events since that the "OK" button validates the form, and the "Cancel" button closes the form. thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't as some OS's don't have them. This is specific for Android.

Generally if the picker value changes revalidate if it didn't change don't.

The underlying [Display picker API](https://www.codenameone.com/javadoc/com/codename1/ui/Display.html#showNativePicker-int-com.codename1.ui.Component-java.lang.Object-java.lang.Object-) includes this to some degree as it will return null for canceled operations.

Comment: Thanks Shai for this clarification

Answer (score 0):

I believe you could subclass it and override the showDialog method. Dialogs usually return a boolean value, so you could store that in a local variable and then when the dialog is disposed take whatever action is needed.

Comment: Thanks for the information but it seems that Dialog is not used in the case of nativePicker. Any other ideas would be welcome ;)